# Visual studio 2012 debugging - stop when the project/namespace is being hit

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012, breakpoints

I am currently debugging large project, I put a breakpoint on the starting point of the application, but it takes forever to hold f10 until it gets into the location I want it to get.

Is there any way to tell the debugger to hold f10 until it gets to a project or the namespace that I want to stop it on?

Comment: Why don't you put the breakpoint where u want to stop? it will automatically stop on the place where u placed the breakpoint

Comment: I think its looping that's why it passing there for multiple times before going to another breakpoint. Why don't you put your breakpoint directly to the line where you want to go? :3

Comment: Maybe because I don't know where I want to go?

Comment: It isn't exactly what a debugger was designed for.  But can certainly be used for that.  You'll however have to spend some time to learn basic debugging commands, there's more than F10.  Step-over and Step-out and breakpoints are key tools to skip the dreary seen-it-before moments.  Using 3 fingers instead of 1 is essential.

Comment: @HansPassant: Yeah, but I'd rather use my three fingers for that exact namespace, instead of lurking few hundred projects away. ;)

Answer (score 0):

just right click on your breakpoint, there are various options for filters, location, etc.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx